# Fetch subcategory in fetched category

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

What i am trying to build is next. Fetch all my menu categories and display them, then fetch all subcategories for each category special all display it also. I hope you understand what i want and saying. I got lost in code and don't now how to do this. Here is my code, hope you can help me.

Here is table structure.

**subcategory table**

| id | subcategory_name | id_category |

**category table**

| id | category |

id_category is connected with id in category table

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <?php
          $pdo = connect();             
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM category";
          $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
          $query->execute();
          $row = $query->fetchAll();      

          foreach ($row as $rs) { ?>

            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo $rs['category'] ?><span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <?php
                $sql = "SELECT subcategory.subcategory_name, subcategory.id_category, category.id, category.category
                        FROM subcategory
                        INNER JOIN category
                        WHERE subcategory.id_category = category.category";
                $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $query->execute();
                $subcat = $query->fetchAll();      

                foreach ($subcat as $sub) { ?>

                <li><a href="#"><?php echo $sub['subcategory_name'] ?></a></li>

                <?php } ?>

              </ul>  
            </li>

          <?php } ?>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="includes/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just didn't understand the INNER JOIN sql select statement. You have to declare the relation of the second table with the first one:

```
SELECT column_list
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON join_condition1
WHERE where_conditions;
```

Join condition in where you want to put the "subcategory.id_category = category.category" part of your query. Maybe leave out the actual WHERE clause?
Hope it helps.
Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Edit:
WHat I was proposing pointed to rewrite the complete code to do it in one query. But your code could be simplified like this quickly using the already captured variable with the first sql query:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <?php
          $pdo = connect();             
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM category";
          $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
          $query->execute();
          $row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);      

          foreach ($row as $rs) { ?>

            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo $rs['category'] ?><span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <?php
                $sql = "SELECT subcategory_name, id_category
                        FROM subcategory
                        WHERE id_category = '".$rs['id']."'";
                $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $query->execute();
                $subcat = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);      

                foreach ($subcat as $sub) { ?>

                <li><a href="#"><?php echo $sub['subcategory_name'] ?></a></li>

                <?php } ?>

              </ul>  
            </li>

          <?php } ?>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="includes/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
```

Comment: can you edit my code if its not a problem? I am trying but can't get it work. Can it work this way?

Comment: thank you, it looks promising but still does not work, no error's, it just don't show subcategory

Comment: I've edited so maybe you need to get the rows as a associative array, maybe that's the problem. If not may is not a SQL problem (?)

Comment: Well still not working, same thing. No error just don't show nothing. Everything looks good and query works fine, where else can problem be...i don't see anything wrong?

Comment: Could you show your tables structure? Are you shure that `subcategory.id_category` matches `category.category`? Could it be `category.id`? That would leave the `WHERE` clause inside the loop like this: `WHERE id_category = '".$rs['id']."'";`

Comment: That was the problem, tables didn't match. So your last comment is the correct answer, thank you! If you can edit your answer i will approve it .